# push_back crashed when using std::vector if the type only defined copy constructor with c++11

Tags: c++

The code like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    int i;
    double d;
};

class Boo
{
public:
    Boo() : fptr(nullptr) 
    {
        std::cout << "Boo default construct..." << std::endl;
    }
    Boo(int i, double d):fptr(new Foo{i,d})
    {
    }

    Boo(const Boo &rhs) :fptr(new Foo{rhs.fptr->i,rhs.fptr->d})
    {
    }

    Foo *fptr;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Boo> vec(1);
    Boo b(42, 10.24);
    vec.push_back(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Env: Ubuntu 16.4 LTS with gcc 5.4
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -g

./test

If define move constructor,this will work good.
I debuged it several hours but can not found what's wrong with it, maybe because some rules in c++ 11 that i did't know.

Could somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: You didn't define a user-defined copy constructor or destructor.

Comment: You've to free the memory you allocated via `new` using `delete` otherwise you'll have **memory leak** in your program.

Comment: At the duplicate link, go to the **Managing resources** section.  The code there is almost identical to what you are trying to do (and what is missing).

Comment: The root reason of this problem is that the std::vector<Boo> vec(1) has one element of Boo with  fptr is null. When push_back(b), at that time the capcity is 1, so vector must reallocating to increase the capcity to accommodate more elements.At that time, copy constructor has been called and it will dereference nullptr.

Comment: if move constructor added, the move constructor will be called priority when reallocating. So this problem will be avoided.Otherwise, this code above is missing Destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that in the copy constructor of `Boo` you're dereferencing a `nullptr`. This is because when you wrote:

```
std::vector<Boo> vec(1); //this creates a vector of size 1 using Boo's default constrcutor
```

This is what happens due to the above statement:

1. The above statement creates a vector named `vec` of size `1` using `Boo`'s **default constructor**.
2. This means that there is already `1` `Boo` object inside `vec`. Moreover since this `Boo` object was created using the default constructor, its `fptr` is set to `nullptr`.

---

Now, when you wrote:

```
vec.push_back(b);// this adds/push_back object b onto the vector vec so that now its size will be 2
```

Now, these are the important things that you have to note here:

1. The vector `vec` has already `1` `Boo` object inside it which has its `fptr` as `nullptr`.
2. Now you're adding one more element `b` into the vector, due to which **reallocation** may happen. And **if/when** this reallocation happens, the **copy constructor** of `Boo` will be used.
3. And when this copy constructor is used to copy the **already present** `Boo` object, it **dereferences** its `fptr`. But since that `fptr` is `nullptr` and we know that dereferencing a `nullptr` is **undefined behavior**, so this may cause the program to **segmentation fault** as in your case.

##### Solution

**First**, before dereferencing `fptr` you should check it is a null pointer or not.

**Second**, you **must** free the memory you allocated via `new` using `delete`. This can be done by adding a **destructor** for class `Boo` and using `delete` on `fptr` inside it.

If you don't free this memory then you will have **memory leak** in your program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo
{
    int i;
    double d;
};

class Boo
{
public:
    Boo() : fptr(nullptr) 
    {
        std::cout << "Boo default construct..." << std::endl;
    }
    Boo(int i, double d):fptr(new Foo{i,d})
    {
        std::cout <<"Boo parameterized const"<<std::endl;
    }

    Boo(const Boo &rhs) 
    {
        std::cout <<"Boo copy const"<<std::endl;
        //add a check before dereferencing
        if(rhs.fptr!= nullptr)
        {
           fptr = new Foo{rhs.fptr->i,rhs.fptr->d};
           std::cout<<"i: "<<rhs.fptr->i <<" d: "<<rhs.fptr->d<<std::endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout<<"nullptr found"<<std::endl;
        }
        
       
    }

    Foo *fptr;
    //add destructor
    ~Boo()
    {
        std::cout<<"Boo destructor"<<std::endl;
        //for debugging check if we got a null pointer
        if(fptr!=nullptr) //just a check before deleting, you can remove this. This is for printing(debugging) when we get a nullptr
        {
            delete fptr;
            fptr = nullptr;
            std::cout<<"delete done"<<std::endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout<<"null pointer found while delete"<<std::endl;
        }
        
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Boo> vec(1);
    Boo b(42, 10.24);
    vec.push_back(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Boo` copy constructor derefernces a pointer `fptr` that may be null.

A `std::vector::push_back` may reallocate vector storage.  Reallocating may use copy constructors.

That is what is happening in your program.  You are copying a `Boo` that has a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is very simple but helped me a lot.